# Scale variable to be within 0-100 value range

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random, scale

I have created a random array :

```
X = np.random.random_sample(70)
```

How can I scale `X` to be within a range of `0 -100`?

Answer (score 1):

```
np.random.randint(0, 101, 70)
```

This will draw 70 random sample between 0 and 100.

Link to docs : [Numpy Random int within range](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)